# Issues with overwriting crafting recipe in Minecraft Data Pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I'm new to making resource packs for Minecraft Java and have decided to try to create some custom crafting. I've tried to change the recipe for black dye, requiring you to craft it with a diamond. I have applied the resource pack and moved it to the top, although, when I place a diamond in the crafting grid, nothing happens. What have I done wrong?

My directory structure is as follows:

```
My Resource Pack/
├─ data/
│  ├─ minecraft/
│  │  ├─ recipes/
│  │  │  ├─ black_dye.json
├─ pack.mcmeta
```

My pack.mcmeta is the following.

```
{
    "pack": {
        "pack_format": 8,
        "description": "Makes it easier and cheeper to craft items such as blocks of ore"
    }
}
```

Just as a test, I made a diamond craft black dye with the following code.

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shapeless",
  "group": "black_dye",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "item": "minecraft:diamond"
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "item": "minecraft:black_dye"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have mixed up [resource packs](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Resource_Pack) and [data packs](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Data_pack). The two are not the same